# How to get the names of all nodes and attributes of an xml in php?

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I'm using the following code to get the xml object of a file:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($tmp_dir);
```

and after a long research I found how to get the values of all nodes by using a foreach loop, is there a way to get the names? I need it so I can parse any xml like magicparse (http://www.magicparser.com/)

Example input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root attribute="example_attribute">
  <Node 1>
    <Nested Node>
    <Nested Node>
  </Node 1>
  <Node 2>
  </Node 2>
</Root>
```

Desire output:

```
Root
 -@attribute
 -Node 1
 -Node 1/Nested Node
 -Node 2
```

Comment: what's your goal with this?

Comment: my goal is parse any xml file to generate the correspondent code with the parsed structured

Comment: Please show a sample input and your desired output.

Comment: Why do you want to parse "Any XML"? DOM, XMLReader and SimpleXML parse "any XML" and allow you to read it. XPath allows you to fetch data using expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get all node and attribute names

```
<?php

$xf = file_get_contents($xmlFileName);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xf);

displayNode($xml, 0);

function displayNode($node, $offset) {

    if (is_object($node)) {
        $node = get_object_vars($node);
        foreach ($node as $key => $value) {
            echo str_repeat(" ", $offset) . "-" . $key . "\n";
            displayNode($value, $offset + 1);
        }
    } elseif (is_array($node)) {
        foreach ($node as $key => $value) {
            if (is_object($value))
                displayNode($value, $offset + 1);
            else
                echo str_repeat(" ", $offset) . "-" . $key . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works pretty nice when the xml doesn't have a namespace, for some reason it doesn't display anything when the document has one like <arfa:Document></arfa:Document>.